# Why do I keep getting a null exception when the file is not empty?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run the code, the message "null" is printed out. But the file is filled with data and is in the correct place. Why am I getting this null exception?

This is the class that reads the file:

```
public class ScoreBoard {
private ArrayList<QuizTaker> scoreBoard = new ArrayList<QuizTaker>();

public ScoreBoard() {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Scores.txt"));

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextLine();
            int score = reader.nextInt();
            reader.nextLine();

            QuizTaker taker = new QuizTaker(name, score);

            scoreBoard.add(taker);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is what the Scores.txt file:

```
Edward 
5

Jimmy
4

Poke
6

Luke 
8

Andy 
9
```

Comment: You read from the file 3 times without checking if there is available content

Comment: You're running this in eclipse; the path it is running in is not the path that the file is in. `System.out.println(new File("Scores.txt").getCanonicalPath());`

Comment: To add to the above comment, try using the full path from root for `Scores.txt` and see if that works.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and replace System.out.println(e.getMessage()) with `e.printStackTrace();`.  Then you’ll know exactly what happened, where, and why.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. e.printStackTrace() would be more helpful to identify the error and fix it.